# Base64 decode no reduce el tamaño?

Tags: .net, base64, vbscript, vbs

Necesito usar base64 encode para trasladar un fichero de texto de un disco duro a un servidor.
El proceso ya existe y es un .vbs que abre un fichero Ade texto de, por ejemplo 562Kb, le hace un encode base64 y el resultado lo envía a un webService.
En el webService, se coge lo enviado, se hace un decode base64 y guarda el resultado en un fichero B.
El caso es que los562Kb originales, se convierten en un fichero de 1.124Kb, justo el doble...

Se que el encode amplía el tamaño del fichero porque usa 4bytes para representar 3bytes, por lo que es 2 veces más grande que el fichero sin comprimir.

Pero pensé que luego el "decode" volvería a reducir y dejar el tamaño original...
Por qué no?

Gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El decode deberia devolverlo a su tamaño original... si no es asi, capaz tenes otro problema.. habria que ver un ejemplo...

Comment: el encode si aumenta el tamaño ya que pasa todo a texto plano pero el decode lo regresa a su tamaño original... ya que base64 es un algoritmo de conversion no de compresion°